# Editing an element of NSArray in NSMutableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm creating NSMutableArray here:

```
NSMutableArray *DataBase = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:DataKey] ];
```

And adding object here:

```
 [DataBase insertObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"st", @"s", @"Con, @"S1", @"S2", @"S3", @"S4",@"T1",@"T2",@"T3",@"T4", nil] atIndex: 0];
```

I want to edit one first element of first object. I've tried this `[DataBase objectAtIndex:1][0]`, do i need something like this `[DataBase replaceObjectAtIndex:1] withObject:TempArray];` or there is a better way?

Comment: If the inner array is an NSArray and not an NSMutableArray you can't edit its elements -- you'd need to replace the entire array.  (And, since you're inserting array element 0 in the outer array, that is the one you'd need to access to reach the inner array.)

Comment: so if i change it's type to  NSMutableArray i may do like [[DataBase objectAtIndex:1]objectAtIndex:1]= @"sdf"; ?

Comment: Well, almost.  You'd need to do addObject, insertObject, or (most likely) replaceObjectAtIndex instead of the second objectAtIndex.  Or use the "new" notation `DataBase[1][1] = ...`.

Comment: (Note that, in keeping with standard C coding conventions, you should spell a variable name like "dataBase" with a lower-case first character.)